# How to Link Same Google Analytics Property for Android and iOS to AdMob

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, admob

We have a mobile app for iOS and Android. Both use Google Analytics for tracking the usage.

In the Google Analytics setup, we adhered to [Best Practices for Mobile App Analytics set up](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087?hl=en) and used the same GA property for both apps. This works well so far.

Now, we've added AdMob to monetize the app. In the AdMob web interface, I would like to link the Android and the iOS app to the existing GA properties (AdMob / Analyze / Apps Setup). However, whenever I select the property for one of the apps, it's no longer available to the other one. It seems that AdMob insists on two different properties for the Android and the iOS app (in conflict with the Google Analytics best practice).

Can I solve it without adding new properties? Can I link two apps in AdMob to the same property? Or can I somehow merge the Android and the iOS app into a single app (in AdMob)?

Comment: No, we haven't solved it. We soon abandoned AdMob because the ads were horrible and the expected earnings (according to people with some experience) very low. So we had not need to solve it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the same GA property if you have multiple views on that property. I found a detailed process here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile-app-analytics/_83KYsk-h2E

> If you'd prefer to see the data for the two apps rolled up together, the process is a bit more complex, but still possible. You'll first need to go into Google Analytics and create a new view in your existing Google Analytics account / property. Then, you'll return to AdMob and within 24 hours you should have the option to link the app to this new view instead of creating a new property.